# Backing up a table before deleting all the records and reloading it in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

- I have a table named **abcTbl**, the data in there is populated
  from other tables from a different database. Every time I am loading
  data to **abcTbl**, I am doing a delete all to it and loading the buffer
  data into it.
- This package runs daily. My question is how do I avoid losing data
  from the table **abcTbl** if we fail to load the data into it. So my
  first step is deleting all the data in the **abcTbl** and then
  selecting the data from various sources into a buffer and then
  loading the buffer data into **abcTbl**.
- Since we can encounter issues like failed connections, package
  stopping prematurely, supernatural forces trying to stop/break my
  package from running smoothly, etc. which will end up with the
  package losing all the data in the buffer after I have already
  deleted the data from **abcTbl**.
- My first intuition was to save the data from the **abcTbl** into a
  backup table and then deleting the data in the **abcTbl** but my DBAs
  wouldn't be too thrilled about creating a backup table for in every
  environment for the purpose of this package, and giving me juice to
  create backup tables on the fly and then deleting it again is out of 
  the question too. This data is not business critical and can be repopulated 
  again if lost.

But, what is the best approach here? What are the best practices for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add some code, examples and output that you want into your question. that will help us to help you.

Comment: Back it up into a #temp table. This would automatically be deleted when the connection is closed, e.g. `SELECT * INTO #abcTbl FROM abcTbl` would create the temp table `#abcTbl` and insert all of the data from `abcTbl` into it in one command.

Comment: The best approach is to ask your team and, especially, the person that is in charge. There is no best practice because ETL is always very specific to business requirements. You said that the process can be repeated and the data is not critical. So why do you worry? If the process fails, just re-run it after fixing any problems. Where are your requirements? Again - ASK YOUR TEAM for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

For backing up your table, instead of loading data from one table (Original) to another table (Backup), you can just rename your original table to something (back-up table), create original table again like the back-up table and then drop the renamed table only when your data load is successful. This may save some time to transfer data from one table to another. You may want to test which approach is faster for you depending on your data/table structure etc., But what I wanted to mention is, this is also one of the way to do it. If you have lot of data in that table below approach may be faster.

```
sp_rename 'abcTbl', 'abcTbl_bkp';
```

`CREATE TABLE abcTbl ;`

While creating this table, you can keep similar table structure as that of **abcTbl_bkp**

Load your new data to **abcTbl** table

```
DROP TABLE abcTbl_bkp;
```

Comment: No such command "rename" in tsql. Nor is there a "create ... like " command in tsql.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! That was mySQL syntax, didn't notice this one was for tSQL. Edited the syntax now. But the idea was to rename that table and create a new one and then drop the back-up table.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure this out but I think what you are asking for is a method to capture the older data before loading the new data.  I would agree with your DBA's that a seperate table for every reload would be extremely messy and not very usable if you ever need it.
Instead, create a table that copies your load table but adds a single DateTime field(say history_date).  Each load you would just flow all the data in your primary table to the backup table.  Use a Derived Column task in the Data Flow to add the history_date value to the backup table.
Once the backup table is complete, either truncate or delete the contents of the current table.  Then load the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of created additional tables you can set the package to execute as a single transaction.  By doing this, if any component fails all the tasks that have already executed will be rolled back and subsequent ones will not run.  To do this, set the `TransactionOption` to `Required` on the package.  This will allow that the package will begin a transaction.  After this set all this property to `Supported` for all components that you want to succeed or fail together.  The `Supported` level will have these tasks join a transaction that is already in progress by the parent container, being the package in this case.  If there are other components in the package that you want to commit or rollback independent of these tasks you can place the related objects in a Sequence container, and apply the `Required` level to the Sequence instead.  An important thing to note is that if anything performs a `TRUNCATE` then all other components that access the truncated object will need to have the `ValidateExternalMetadata` option set to `false` to avoid the known blocking issue that is a result of this.